# SQL Server bcp utility does not create the txt file,

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm new to this feature in SQL Server and could use some help. I'm experimenting with the `BCP` utility and the `AdventureWorks2012` database.

I'm attempting to export data to a text file with the BCP utility and the code executes but a file is not created. Can you please look at my code and tell me where the problem(s) is/are.

I'm working out of a local copy of SQL Server Express. Thank you.

```
Declare @sql Varchar(8000)

Select @sql = 'bcp
    + SELECT FirstName, LastName
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person ORDER BY LastName, Firstname
    + queryout C:\Users\David\Desktop\yes.txt + -c -t, -T -S'
+ @@SERVERNAME

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Here is my output when I run the query:

```
output
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]        [-K application intent]  [-l login timeout]
NULL
```

Here is the PRINT output:

```
bcp
    + "SELECT FirstName, LastName
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person ORDER BY LastName, Firstname"
    + queryout C:\Users\David\Desktop\yes.txt -c -t, -T -SHOMEPC\SQLINST01
```

TT's code worked. Here it is:

```
DECLARE @stmt_e VARCHAR(8000);
SET @stmt_e=
    'BCP '+
    '"SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person ORDER BY LastName,Firstname" '+
    'QUERYOUT "C:\Users\David\Desktop\yes.csv" '+
    '-c -t, -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt_e;
```

The instructions for adding system permissions for database engine access can be found at the link below. I had to do this because my SQL Server Instance did not have permission to write to the path I was specifying.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219062.aspx

Comment: add a "" in your select query this will work....

Comment: The `+` symbol has no place in `bcp` command line. Take em out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet should run without problem on any SQL Server. It outputs all table information in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` as a comma separated file in `C:\Temp\information_schema.csv`.

Run this as a sanity check; it works without problem on my system, and it should on your system too. Run this from the `AdventureWorks2012` database. If it doesn't work we'll have to delve deeper.

```
DECLARE @stmt_c VARCHAR(8000);
SET @stmt_c=
    'BCP '+
    '"SELECT*FROM '+QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" '+
    'QUERYOUT "C:\Temp\information_schema.csv" '+
    '-c -t, -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt_c;
```

---

Now if this works, adapt this to your query:

```
DECLARE @stmt_e VARCHAR(8000);
SET @stmt_e=
    'BCP '+
    '"SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person ORDER BY LastName,Firstname" '+
    'QUERYOUT "C:\Users\David\Desktop\yes.txt" '+
    '-c -t, -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt_e;
```

Comment: Thanks TT. That does work but with one Caveat. It only works when I specify the "Temp" folder. Do you have any insight to why?

Comment: @BrownEyeBoy Because the user account you logged in with in SQL Server doesn't have the proper access rights for the folder you are writing to.

Comment: Thanks TT. That did it. I granted write permissions for my SQL Instance in the security options for the directory I was attempting to save to. Used the following instructions to do so. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219062.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Should warpped the query in double quotes. I have removed an extra + before the -c.
You can test out the BCP on command prompt first. make sure it is working before using xp_cmdshell to execute it.

And lastly, i have added a PRINT statement to print out the command for verification

```
Declare @sql Varchar(8000)

Select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT FirstName, LastName '
            + 'FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person '
            + 'ORDER BY LastName, Firstname" '
            + 'queryout C:\Users\David\Desktop\yes.txt -c -t, -T -S'
            + @@SERVERNAME

PRINT @sql -- Print out for verification

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt but your correction did not work.

Comment: any error message ? Please post it. Aso did you try execute the BCP on command prompt direclty ? It is easier to debug from there

Comment: The output in the command prompt is the same as when I run the code in SQL Server. I posted the example above.

Comment: can you do a PRINT @sql and post the result

Comment: Added the PRINT @sql to post.

Comment: i have upated the query above. Please try

Comment: With your updated code and granting the correct permissions this also works. Thanks Squirrel.

Answer (score 1):

This Should work

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000);
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM'+
' AdventureWorks2008.Person.Person ORDER BY FirstName, LastName" queryout'+
' C:\Users\David\Desktop\yes.txt -c -t, -r \r\n -S '+@@servername+' -T';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Comment: You should check the output you generate in eg Notepad++, and go to View>Show Symbol>Show all Characters. You will see that rows are terminated with `\r\r\n` (`{CR}{CR}{LF}`). To have proper row delimiters (for Windows OS), drop the `-r \r\n`.

Comment: Same situation as Squirrel; the code did not create the output file. Thanks anyways.

Comment: But it gave a different response right? If you want to solve this you need to provide more feedback

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with that problem almost whole yesterday and finally it comes out, that the "select" query is too complex (probably) to be processed by the `xp_cmdshell` command directly.

I have a query joining and aggregating many tables from different databases.
Trying to save its results to txt file directly via `xp_cmdshell` always resulted in the output presented by BrownEyeBoy, eventhought the select itself was working correctly.

I've bypassed this simply by inserting the results of the complex query into temporary table and then execute the `xp_cmdshell` on the temporary table like:

```
DECLARE
@SQL    varchar(max)
, @path varchar(max) = 'D:\TMP\TMP_' + convert(varchar(10), convert(date, getdate(), 21)) + '.txt'
, @BCP  varchar(8000)
;

INSERT INTO ##TMP
{COMPLEX SELECT}
;

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ##TMP;
SET @BCP = 'bcp "' + @sql + '" queryout "' + @path + '" -c -T -S.'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcp;
```

Not nice, but easy and working.

Answer (score 1):

Put the complete `bcp` query in one not to change the line while writing `bcp` query.

You can write your query as:

```
Declare @sql Varchar(8000)

Select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person ORDER BY LastName, Firstname " queryout "C:\Users\David\Desktop\yes.txt" -Usa -Ppassw0rd -c -t, -T -S'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```